# Azure Service Bus management using SAS Token and new Java Libraries

Tags: java, azure, authentication, azureservicebus

I have Java code where I need to create a subscription to an Azure Service Bus topic. I am using the latest Azure Management Library (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java), but I am having trouble with the authentication. What I have is Shared Access Signature (SAS) Key that I obtained from the Azure portal, but it wants a "service principal registration" (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md).

I was trying to follow the Microsoft tutorial that authenticates with SAS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions), but it seems to be using an older library for the Java SDK. Is there a way use a SAS token using the new libraries (i.e. using `Azure.authenticate()`)?

My Maven dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-mgmt-servicebus</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Currently downgrading the azure package to 0.9.8 is working, giving me access to the old libraries that can configure with SAS. Would still like to know if this functionality is meant to be supported with the latest code...

Comment: were you able to figure it out?